# P2V converting windows server 2008 Failure

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-vcenter, physical-to-virtual

I am trying Virtualize my windows 2008 Server , & unfortunately have been running to this error msg 1% after the converter starts.  The Error Msg is "Unable to create a VSS Snapshot of the Source Volume 2147754767 (0x8004230f) can any one help? thanks

Comment: Do you have any FAT volumes on the existing server? have you tried doing a cold-conversion with the machine powered off?

Comment: hi Chopper3, the system is based on usual NTFS system. I have note tried the cold-conversion.  Appreciate if you could guide me on that

Comment: I trust you are using the [vCenter Converter Standalone](http://www.vmware.com/go/download-converter) for the conversion? If so, are you using the latest version? Have you seen [this vmWare KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1019690) on this topic?

Comment: HI all... Thank you for all your posts.... The problem was the USB Devices.... as soon as I removed them it worked flawlessly... again.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your posts.... The problem was the USB Devices.... as soon as I removed them it worked flawlessly... again.. as a side not I like to add that it will not harm if you put your VSS on manual if its on automatic.... that should do the trick!.....